# For what $m$ does $\iint_{\mathbb{R^2}}\frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^m}dxdy$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

For what $m$ does $\iint_{\mathbb{R^2}}\frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^m}dxdy$ converge or diverge?

---

Attempt: We write the double integral as
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R^2}}\frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^m}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^m}dxdy$$
We note that out integrand is symmetric, thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^m}dxdy=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^m}dxdy$$
We now establish polar coordinates $x=r\cos{\theta}$,$y=r\sin{\theta}$. Then (this is where I'm slighly unsure), we have integration bounds $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, $0\leq r \leq \infty$. Recalling that the jacobian of this change of variables is simply $r$, we are now considering the integral
$$4\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^m}d\theta dr=8\pi\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^m} dr$$
This is trivially integrated using $u=1+r^2$, which yields
$$8\pi\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^m} dr=8\pi \frac{(1+r^2)^{1-m}}{1-m} \Big|_0^\infty$$
Then it should stand to reason that the integral diverges for $m\leq1 $ and converges for $m>1$. There was no answer provided in the exercise, so I used some python code to check, and it appears to converge for $m=0$, but otherwise seems to agree with my result (however code can be unshaky at times, so I turned to you guys). Input would be much appriciated!

Comment: It can't possibly converge for $m=0$ because that yields $\int_{\mathbb R ^2} 1=\infty$

Comment: Certainly does not converge for $m=0$.

Comment: Your work is right, it converges iff $m>1$.

Comment: @runway44 Great! Thank you :)

Comment: This is only incidental to the important points here, but: you folded the whole plane onto a quarter plane, but then when you parameterized it in polar coordinates you covered the whole plane again ($0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq r$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$) so the value you get is four times what it should be.  

Also "$r \leq \infty$" does not make sense, if you're going to write the upper bound as an inequality it is $r < \infty$.

Comment: @JBL so we should integrate with respect to $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and integrate with respect to $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$ (i.e $r < \infty$)?

Comment: @William Not $\pi/4$ but $\pi/2$ (the first quadrant makes an angle of $90^\circ = \frac{2\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ at the origin).  Or skip the first four-fold simplification (which ultimately doesn't make your life any easier).

Comment: @JBL right sorry! Quick typo! Yeah, I suppose we could simply skip that part. If we skip the four-fold, does this mean we are integrating $r$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @William: if you want to integrate over the full plane $-\infty < x < \infty$, $-\infty < y < \infty$, the usual way to do that in polar coordinates is $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, $0 \leq r < \infty$ (which is to say: all possible directions, positive distances).  There are other possibilities, one of which is $0 \leq \theta < \pi$, $-\infty < r < \infty$ also covers the whole plane (half of possible directions, both positive and negative distances to make up the other half).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this is to use a trigonometric substitution.

Let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ then your integral becomes
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^m}drd\theta$$
let us first study
$$ K=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^m}dr$$
let $u=r^2+1$ then $du=2dr$
$$\Rightarrow K=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}u^{-m}du=\frac{1}{u^{m-1}(2-2m)}\Big\vert_{1}^{+\infty}$$
which only converges for $m>1$. And, for $m>1$, $K=-\frac{1}{4(1-m)}\ne 0$ which is not a negative number. Now
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^m}drd\theta$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}Kd\theta$$
$$\Rightarrow I=K\theta\Big\vert_{0}^{2\pi}$$
which converges.

So for  $m>1$, your integral converges

Comment: That’s what the OP does